# Is it possible to get step-by-step information about qiskit transpilation?

Tags: qiskit, transpile

Is it possible to get the information about the step by step transpilation? I have circuits that I know how it is more or less structured after the transpilation, but when I join them to create a bigger circuit it's difficult to see how qiskit arrives at the final result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to debug `transpile` is via the `callback` option. From [the documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/compiler.html#qiskit.compiler.transpile):

> A callback function that will be called after each pass execution. The function will be called with 5 keyword arguments,    * pass_: the
> pass being run.
>
> - dag: the dag output of the pass.
> - time: the time to execute the pass.
> - property_set: the property set.
> - count: the index for the pass execution.
>
> [...] For example:
>
> ```python
> def callback_func(**kwargs):
>     pass_ = kwargs['pass_']
>     dag = kwargs['dag']
>     time = kwargs['time']
>     property_set = kwargs['property_set']
>     count = kwargs['count']
>
> transpile(circ, callback=callback_func)
> ```

You can use `callback` to inspect intermediate states of the [`DAGCircuit`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.dagcircuit.DAGCircuit.html), which is the internal representation of your circuit.

### Example

My usual workflow starts with detecting the interesting "jump". Most of the time `count_ops` does the trick.

```python
def callback_func(**kwargs):
    dag = kwargs['dag']
    pass_ = kwargs['pass_']
    count = kwargs['count']
    print(count, pass_.name(), dag.count_ops())
```

When executing with this callback, the output looks something like this:

```sh
0 ContainsInstruction {'quantum_volume_[3,4,42]': 1}
1 UnitarySynthesis {'quantum_volume_[3,4,42]': 1}
2 HighLevelSynthesis {'quantum_volume_[3,4,42]': 1}
3 UnrollCustomDefinitions {'u': 32, 'cx': 12}
4 BasisTranslator {'cx': 12, 'rz': 96, 'sx': 64}
...
```

I might notice that, say, `UnrollCustomDefinitions` changes the basis is a way I was not expected. Then, I focus on that one, getting the circuit before and after:

```
from qiskit.converters import dag_to_circuit

def callback_func(**kwargs):
    dag = kwargs['dag']
    count = kwargs['count']
    if 2 <= count <= 3:
        print(dag_to_circuit(dag))
```

This will print the circuit at `count` 2 and 3 (before and after `UnrollCustomDefinitions`).

**Important note**: Consider setting `transpile(..., seed_transpiler=<a number>)` to make sure the transpilation process is always the same.

### Other tools

Alternatively, you can set a breakpoint inside the `callback_func` definition to explore the transpilation with your usually debugger. For some situations, this might be the prefer way, instead of rerunning transpile several times, like in the example.

There are other tools, like Harshit Gupta's https://github.com/TheGupta2012/qiskit-timeline-debugger which provide you a more user friendly way to see your circuit evolution.

Comment: Is it possible to ask for an example? I just want to print all the pipeline from the beginning to the final circuit presented in the notebook.

Comment: example added. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Many thanks for the example (callbacks is something, since ns3) I wasn't expected to find too often. 

It seems everything will work pretty well, thanks a lot!